# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'. > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: flutter-dependencies

I am getting this error for last 3-4 days, My app was running fine but suddenly it start giving this error

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip

compileSdkVersion 29
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 29

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter {
url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
```

}